# Difference between Shell (VB6) and System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()

Tags: vb.net, shell, vb6

I'm stuck because (as I think the same code) works on VB6, but not on VB.NET.

My code in VB6 is:

```
Dim ProcID As Long
ProcId = Shell(uPath, WindowStyle)
```

The .NET equivalent is

```
Dim myProcess As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(uPath)
```

The .NET code throws a Win32 FileNotFoundException while the VB6 code works perfectly fine.

The path for both versions is

```
7z e "d:\myfile.7z" -o"d:\"
```

VB6 CurDir() returns

```
C:\Program Files\7-Zip
```

And VB.NET Directory.GetCurrentDirectory.ToString() returns

```
C:\Program Files\7-Zip
```

What else might be the difference?

Comment: Strange, it works if I just say d:\myfile.7z -o"d:\" instead of "d:\myfile.7z" -o"d:\"

Comment: Separate the executable & command line: `.Start("7z.exe", uPath);`  where `uPath` is `e "d:\myfile.7z" -o"d:\" `

Comment: Could you try 7z e "d:\\myfile.7z" (double backslash is often required when quotted)